# How to install Apache Solr on Mac OS?

Tags: solr, terminal

I need to create an information retrieval system using Solr.Please assist how to do that on Mac computer.

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/installing-solr.html

Comment: The description in the reference guide works as you'd expect under OS X: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/installing-solr.html is the description for 8.5. Download the archive, unpack it and run `bin/solr start` to start Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick notes on how to install solr on a Mac.

download openjdk.  I downloaded openjdk-14.0.1_osx-x64_bin.tar

set the PATH environment variable to include
“`your_path/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`”

```
download ant (to compile solr). apache-ant-1.9.15-bin.tar.bz2
```

add to the PATH again.  “your_path/apache-ant-1.9.15/bin”

from solr README.md, “ant compile”

from solr README.md, “ant server”

chmod +x solr* from the solr/bin directory

bin/solr start

test http://localhost:8983/solr/